# How to make Thread in android run infinitely

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, java-threads

```
   Runnable updateSeekbar=new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            while (true) {
                if (!isPlayerDead) {
                    Log.d("Threads", "Thread is running successfully.");
                    int progress=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                    seekBar.setProgress(progress);
                    Log.d("Seekbar",seekBar.getProgress()+"");
                    Log.d("MediaProgress",mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()+"");
                    String s=modifyTime(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 / 60) + ":" + modifyTime((mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000) % 60);
                    progressTime.setText(s);

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
Executor executor=new Executor() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        Thread thread=new Thread(command);
        thread.start();
    }
};
```

executor.execute(updateSeekbar);

> 

Actually the problem is that the thread dies before the mediaplayer can send updated position. I have made the thread in an endless while loop but still it dies. How can I make it run infinitely till the activity gets destroyed.
The thread only runs for a couple of seconds and then dies. I want it to run infinitely till the activity gets destroyed. All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: If you set the try/catch in the while loop, will it be fine ?

Comment: What about `services`?

Answer (score 1):

when `mediaPlayer` isn't in proper state and you try to call some improper method then some `Exception` may be thrown, and you are catching it OUTside `while(true)` loop. try to move `try{}catch` inside `while(true)`, then your `Thread` will run infinitely

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try{
            if (!isPlayerDead) {
            
            // current code
            
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SystemClock.sleep(20); // some bonus line
    } // end of while
}
```

btw. give some rest for UI between iterations, e.g. by putting `SystemClock.sleep(20);` after every calculation (last line before closing bracket). you don't need so often progress refreshing, in current code it may happen even few times more often than system is capable to draw (in most often 60Hz case)

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem and now the loop is running infinitely.